# facebooksdk 3.1 for iOS creates weird behavior

Tags: ios, facebook

I installed the new FB-SDK - and now my xcode's acting up...

NSLog(@"...") is no longer working (and yes, I tried it even in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method).

When I add a breakpoint to the code the app crashes, with an arbitrary error...

I followed the installation guide closely (twice) and am sure I got it right...
I did move the FB-SDK Folder to another folder than it was installed by the installer, though.
The 3 Frameworks (Accounts/AdSupport/Social) are set to «optional» as I'm deploying to iOS 5.1

Any ideas?

[Edit solved]

Thanks to this guy - it's working again: http://davidbits.blogspot.ch/2012/03/ios-nslog-is-not-working-on-simulator.html

Had to delete all the app-versions on simulator and now it's working again...

Comment: And you're not getting any warnings or errors? Try creating a brand new project. My Xcode went nuts a week or so ago, wasn't giving me any error messages anymore, it was strange and boiled down to a bad library import from one of my library search paths.

Comment: Nope - no warnings. And everything is working fine in other projects (opened at the same time).